# Use functions in Python and Nodejs in Firebase project

Tags: python, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to have Google Cloud functions in Python and Nodejs combined in one Firebase project?

I found some documentation to set the functions runtime in firebase.json, but what if you have functions both Python and Nodejs?

Comment: Have you seen the documentation on the matter? https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions?gen=2nd#managing_multiple_source_packages_monorepo

Comment: Ooh... I didn't know that. That sounds like an answer @DougStevenson 

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @DougStevenson - after asking my question, I saw the same page - working with that now - but so it's good that you confirm that this is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.  I suggest reviewing the [documentation on Managing multiple source packages (monorepo)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions?gen=2nd#managing_multiple_source_packages_monorepo).  The very first example at that link shows an example with both node and python functions:

```
$  tree .
├── firebase.json
├── teamA
│   ├── main.py
│   └── requirements.txt
└── teamB
    ├── index.js
    └── package.json
```

With the configuration:

```
"functions": [
  {
    "source": "teamA",
    "codebase": "team-a"
  },
  {
    "source": "teamB",
    "codebase": "team-b"
  },
]
```